# Middleman INIT Error

Tags: bundler, middleman

I recently just took over a middleman-netlify website.

```
git clone {website codebase url}
bundle install
bundle update
middleman init (error issue)
```

I don't know what to do next.
I have tried the following

- uninstall middleman and gems, reinstalled, and restart MAC
- `gem cleanup`
- `gem update`

```
[polytronixglass (master)]$ middleman init
/Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:23:in `source': uninitialized constant Gem::Source (NameError)
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:65:in `extension_dir'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:46:in `gem_build_complete_path'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2174:in `missing_extensions?'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:71:in `contains_requirable_file?'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1067:in `block in find_in_unresolved'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1067:in `each'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1067:in `find_all'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1067:in `find_in_unresolved'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:23:in `source'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:65:in `extension_dir'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:46:in `gem_build_complete_path'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2174:in `missing_extensions?'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:71:in `contains_requirable_file?'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1067:in `block in find_in_unresolved'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1067:in `each'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1067:in `find_all'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1067:in `find_in_unresolved'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler/settings.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler.rb:209:in `settings'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler.rb:438:in `configure_gem_path'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler.rb:433:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler.rb:62:in `configure'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler.rb:126:in `definition'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler.rb:93:in `setup'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/middleman-core-3.4.1/lib/middleman-core/load_paths.rb:29:in `setup_load_paths'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/middleman-core-3.4.1/bin/middleman:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/middleman:22:in `load'
from /Users/StephanieApril/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/middleman:22:in `<main>'
```

Development Environment 
    gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
activesupport (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1)
addressable (2.4.0)
autoprefixer-rails (6.4.1.1)
backports (3.6.8)
bigdecimal (1.2.7, default: 1.2.6)
bundler (1.13.0)
capybara (2.8.1, 2.4.4)
chunky_png (1.3.7)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
compass (1.0.3)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
contracts (0.14.0, 0.13.0)
directory_watcher (1.5.1, 1.4.1)
dotenv (2.1.1)
em-websocket (0.5.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.2.0.1)
execjs (2.7.0, 1.4.1)
fast_blank (1.0.0)
fastimage (2.0.0)
ffi (1.9.14)
haml (4.0.7)
hamster (3.0.0)
hashie (3.4.4)
hike (2.1.3, 1.2.3)
hooks (0.4.1)
http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.6, default: 0.4.3)
json (2.0.2, 1.8.3, default: 1.8.1)
kramdown (1.12.0)
libv8 (5.3.332.38.1 x86_64-darwin-15, 3.16.14.15 x86_64-darwin-15)
listen (3.0.8)
memoist (0.15.0)
middleman (4.1.10, 3.4.1)
middleman-autoprefixer (2.7.0)
middleman-blog (4.0.1)
middleman-cli (4.1.10)
middleman-core (4.1.10, 3.4.1)
middleman-livereload (3.4.6, 3.3.4)
middleman-ngannotate (1.0.2)
middleman-sprockets (4.0.0, 3.4.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.9.0)
multi_json (1.12.1)
nokogiri (1.6.8)
padrino-helpers (0.13.3.2, 0.12.8.1)
padrino-support (0.13.3.2, 0.12.8.1)
parallel (1.9.0)
pkg-config (1.1.7)
psych (2.1.1, default: 2.0.8)
rack (2.0.1, 1.6.4)
rack-livereload (0.3.16)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails-assets-jquery (2.1.4)
rails-assets-parsleyjs (2.1.3)
rake (11.2.2, default: 10.4.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
rb-inotify (0.9.7)
rb-kqueue (0.2.4)
rdoc (4.2.2, default: 4.2.0)
ref (2.0.0)
rubygems-update (2.6.6, 1.8.24)
sass (3.4.22)
servolux (0.12.0)
slop (4.4.1, 3.3.2)
sprockets (3.7.0, 2.12.4)
sprockets-helpers (1.2.1, 1.1.0)
sprockets-sass (1.3.1)
therubyracer (0.12.2)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.5, 1.4.1)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
uber (0.0.15)
uglifier (3.0.2, 2.7.2)
xpath (2.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `middleman server` in order to preview your project or `middleman build` to build it. `middleman init` command is to generate the project directory something that you **already have done** by cloning the project repo